# Why is Postgres Superuser Required for Access to My Database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a common user, `mygs_user`, across three databases:  `mydatamodel`, `mygs`, and `Newdatabase` (names changed to protect the innocent).

I've 'inherited' the first two databases, and have created a third (`Newdatabase`), whose security must closely replicate the original two--including using the same user-name and role.

The problem is while the two original databases do not have explicit privileges, the common user, `mygs_user`, can access them just fine.  The third (`Newdatabase`) does not allow access unless I modify the common user to be a super-user, which obviously is not a best-practice.

Of course, I've tried setting the security settings of my NewDB to settings of the original ones with no dice.

Here are the two original databases:

`mydatamodel`

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatamodel
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = datamodel_tablespace
       LC_COLLATE = 'English, United States'
       LC_CTYPE = 'English, United States'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

`mygs`

```
CREATE DATABASE mygs
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = mygs_tablespace
       LC_COLLATE = 'English, United States'
       LC_CTYPE = 'English, United States'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

...and here is the new database:

```
CREATE DATABASE "NewDatabase"
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'English, United States'
       LC_CTYPE = 'English, United States'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
GRANT CONNECT, TEMPORARY ON DATABASE "NewDatabase" TO public;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE "NewDatabase" TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE "NewDatabase" TO mygs_user;
```

The two original occupy separate tablespaces, while the new one doesn't:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE mygs_tablespace
  OWNER postgres
  LOCATION 'c:/MYGS_Database/PostgreSQL';



CREATE TABLESPACE datamodel_tablespace
  OWNER postgres
  LOCATION 'c:/MYGS_Database/MyDataModel';
```

This is the the commmon user:

```
CREATE ROLE mygs_user LOGIN
  SUPERUSER NOINHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE;
GRANT "MYGS" TO mygs_user;
```

...and the common role:

```
CREATE ROLE "MYGS"
  NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE;
```

Here are the pg_hba.conf file contents:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

How can I grant access to the common user for the third database without granting superuser privileges?

Comment: Because of `GRANT CONNECT, TEMPORARY ON DATABASE "NewDatabase" TO public` any user should be able to connect to it. Please provide the error message if that's not the case.

Comment: The error was "Can't connect to this relation, tablename".  You're right, the access privileges were set at the table-level for the two original databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further inspection, the privileges were set to authorize the the "MYGS" role at the object-level, with no explicit privileges at the database level.  The problem is resolved by the following code, for each object-type:

**Tables:**

```
ALTER TABLE tableNameHere OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE dtm_tableNameHereTO postgres;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON TABLE tableNameHere TO "MYGS";
```

**...functions:**

```
ALTER FUNCTION functionNameHere(..) OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION functionNameHere(..) TO postgres;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION functionNameHere(..) TO "MYGS";
```

**...and sequences:**

```
ALTER TABLE sequenceNameHere OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE sequenceNameHere TO postgres;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON TABLE sequenceNameHere TO "MYGS";
```

Although, the postgres user is not necessary for the solution to work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to allow connecting to this database in `pg_hba.conf` configuration file.

You should probably add there something like:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   Newdatabase     MYGS                                    md5
```

Comment: Tometzky, Great thought! However, we already have open access configured in the pg_hba:

host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5

Comment: Tometzky, I've updated my question with the pg_hba.conf file.